# PDO rollback and beginTransaction , cannot work more than 1 query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, rollback

The first query will execute successfully, but for the second query, it doesn't work.
The following is the coding which I declare my database and executes two of the queries:

```
$db = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$servername ; Database=$databasename", $UserId, $pwd);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

$db->beginTransaction();

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO Header "
        . "(Number,Date)"
        . "VALUES (:Number, :Date)";

try 
{
   $stmt2 = $db->prepare($sql2);   
   $stmt2->bindParam("Number", $Number);
   $stmt2->bindParam("Date", $Date);
   $stmt2->execute();

   $sql3 = "UPDATE table2 
            SET Number= :Number
            WHERE Date= :Date ";

   try 
   {
      $stmt3 = $db->prepare($sql3);  
      $stmt3->bindParam("Number", $Number);
      $stmt3->bindParam("Date ", $Date );

      $stmt3->execute();
   } 
   catch(PDOException $e) 
   {
      $db->rollBack();
   }
   $db->commit();
} 
catch(PDOException $e) 
{
    $db->rollBack();
}
```

I try before set the autocommit to false by `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT,0);` , however, it show the `the auto-commit mode cannot be changed for this driver` error message.

Comment: You dont need to nest the `try/catch` blocks,

Comment: Do you hit the catch block? Can you var_dump the exception in the catch block and post it here?

Comment: That second Query, the UPDATE has no WHERE clause, could that be your problem?

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? A query? A transaction? The whole code? How do you know that?

Comment: I try remove the nested try/catch before, but still be the same, first query can execute, 2nd query cannot. The two queries is just example only. Both of the queries can work well.

Comment: add `throw $e;` after each rollback call

Comment: I try put echo "hello" ; after $stmt2->execute(); , but it do not show any output from it. Is it will autocommit after execute?

Comment: You don't see "hello" because `$stmt2->execute()` throws an exception. But since you catch the exceptions, where you merely do a rollback, without doing some kind of error logging, you're not seeing what went wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the inner try...catch clause because either 1st or 2nd error would trigger the rollback anyway.
**Back to your question**, MySQL might not execute your update statement because your target rows aren't identified by unique id . (unsafe update)

you can override the safe update checkpoint as:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES =0;
do the update..
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES =1;
```

or use unique identifiers in your where clause.

Comment: I try remove the nested try/catch before, but still be the same, first query can execute, 2nd query cannot. The two queries is just example only. Both of the queries can work well if I execute them separately.

Comment: I try put `echo "hello" ;` after `$stmt2->execute();`  , but it do not show any output from it.

Comment: can you do $affected_rows = $stmt2->rowCount(); ? @EliceEe

Comment: So the failing query is sql2/stmt2?